# How to use optional parameter in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a  stored procedure which looks like

```
  CREATE PROCEDURE Update-all  
 (  @RowID INT,
    @Parameter1 NVARCHAR(50),
    @Parameter2 INT
 )
As
....
```

i will be passing @Parameter1 / @Parameter2 based on different conditions.
if i don't pass @Parameter1 / @Parameter2 ,i am getting a error the stored procedure expects @parameter1/@parameter1 which is not supplied . Any ideas  how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to supply default values for the parameters.

```
  CREATE PROCEDURE Update-all  
 (  @RowID INT,
    @Parameter1 NVARCHAR(50) = NULL,
    @Parameter2 INT = NULL
 )
As
....
```

Comment: will this work even if i am not passing  @Parameter1 / @Parameter2 in code ?

Comment: Yes. If you don't pass the parameters, they assume the default value that you specify in the definition of the procedure.

Comment: For those who may not know, here's some information about the parameter sniffing that @onedaywhen mentions above: [I Smell a Parameter!](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/queryoptteam/archive/2006/03/31/565991.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

You need to provide defaults for your parameters. e.g.

```
create procedure Test1 (
   @rowid int,
   @Param1 nvarchar(50) = null,
   @Param2 int = 0 )
as
   print 'rowid=' + convert(varchar(20), @rowid)
   print 'param1=' + @Param1
   print 'param2=' + convert(varchar(20), @Param2)

exec Test1 5
exec Test1 5, 'testing'
exec Test1 5, 'testing', 198
```

Answer (score 0):

Add some default values to parameters:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Update-all  
 (  @RowID INT,
    @Parameter1 NVARCHAR(50) = '',
    @Parameter2 INT = 0
 )
```